# Panda Pivot Table troubles -> No module named style?

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

I am getting this error: `ImportError: No module named style`, which is coming from this import statement: `from openpyxl.style import Style`

Here is my code related to the pivot table:

```
excel = pd.ExcelFile(filename)
df = excel.parse(sheetname=0)
df1 = df[['Product Description', 'Supervisor']]

print df1

table1 = pd.pivot_table(df1, rows = ['Supervisor'],
                           cols = ['Product Description'],
                          values = ['Product Description'],
                           aggfunc = [lambda x: len(x)], fill_value = 0)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(filename)
table1.to_excel(writer, 'Pivot Table')
writer.save()


workbook.save(filename)
```

The only thing I can think of that may cause it would be that the header for the Supervisor column has a style applied to it (which is just applying a bold style to the word 'Supervisor'). Removing the lines that apply the style DOES NOT solve the problem however.

```
supervisorheader = worksheet.cell("CV1")
s = Style(font=Font(bold=True))
supervisorheader.style = s
```

Here is what my data frame looks like:

```
         Product Description Supervisor
0        EXPRESS 12:00 (doc)     Gordon
1     EXPRESS 10:30 (nondoc)    Vinny P
2        EXPRESS 12:00 (doc)    Vinny A
3     EXPRESS 12:00 (nondoc)   Building
4     EXPRESS 12:00 (nondoc)   Building
5     EXPRESS 12:00 (nondoc)   Building
6     EXPRESS 12:00 (nondoc)     Gordon
7   MEDICAL EXPRESS (nondoc)     Gordon
8     EXPRESS 10:30 (nondoc)    Vinny A
9        EXPRESS 12:00 (doc)       Pete
10    EXPRESS 12:00 (nondoc)    Vinny P
11    EXPRESS 10:30 (nondoc)   Building
12    EXPRESS 12:00 (nondoc)     Gordon
13    EXPRESS 12:00 (nondoc)    Vinny A
14    EXPRESS 12:00 (nondoc)   Building
15       EXPRESS 10:30 (doc)     Gordon

[16 rows x 2 columns]
```

And this is the error traceback:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1625, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/harrisonleggio/tdx.py", line 34, in upload
    return process(f.filename)
  File "/home/harrisonleggio/tdx.py", line 201, in process
    table1.to_excel(writer, 'Pivot Table', engine = 'xlsxwriter')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 1204, in to_excel
    startrow=startrow, startcol=startcol)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/excel.py", line 530, in write_cells
    style = self._convert_to_style(cell.style)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/excel.py", line 577, in _convert_to_style
    from openpyxl.style import Style
ImportError: No module named style
```

Comment: Can you try reinstalling `openpyxl`?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is related to your problem, but I tend to avoid creating excelwriter and excelreader objects. Instead, I call `pd.read_excel(filename)` and `df.to_excel(filename)`. As long as you have the proper packages (like openpyxl, xlrd, and xlwt, depending on your file type) pandas will automatically handle the creation and destruction of the i/o objects.

Comment: I changed my lines to that and it's saying that read_excel() takes 2 arguements (1 given) my line says pd.read_excel(filename)

Comment: As a first step I would recommend installing or, if installed, upgrading, XlsxWriter and openpyxl.

Comment: maybe you forgot a 's', `from openpyxl.styles import Style`

Comment: I'm using a linux VM. How can I change the pandas file that says `from openpyxl.style Import Style` to add the S? Also, can I just change that Pandas source file it will fix the issue?

Comment: to edit the file use `vim /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/excel.py` vim or your favorite text editor, you have to test, it have to be an issue about Pandas and Openpxl version

Comment: Okay, I will try that. Also, for some reason this VM downloaded an old version of Pandas for me (0.13.1), and when I try to upgrade it using PIP the installation hangs.

Comment: I changed style to styles and now i'm getting this: http://paste.ubuntu.com/20446311/

Comment: you have to find in the documentation what version of python, pandas, and openpyxl are working together and install them instead of your current ones, because the names of mudule and/or function might differs.

Comment: Okay I managed to update to .16.2 version of Pandas